# Can we do soil analysis for Nitrogen using remote sensing without field data for validation?

Tags: remote-sensing, satellite, analysis, vegetation-index, soil

**Background:**

Remote sensing is used for monitoring land cover change and for monitoring vegetation etc. In addition to that, it is used for soil analysis (alterations in soil properties) as well. There are a number of indices available like NDVI or SAVI etc.

**Question:**

Nitrogen is an essential nutrient found in soil. My question is:

- Can we do soil analysis for **Nitrogen** using **remote sensing** without field data for validation? I mean can we do the analysis by using only the satellites but not examining the soil samples?
- Are there any available indices for measuring Nitrogen content in the soil?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 1):

Of course you can, but you won't know how good your results are.

You can apparently do something with hyperspectral images for wheat: https://doi.org/10.1016/j.fcr.2007.03.023 .

And you can use Sentinel data and then apply clever modelling: https://doi.org/10.1016/j.compag.2019.03.015 .

Honestly, have you tried searching google scholar for "remote sensing nitrogen soil"? That turns up a lot of results.